# Spring Security targetUrlParameter does not redirect

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to redirect the user back to the page where they clicked the login link. (Pages are read-only for non-authenticated users, but writable for logged in users.) How do I redirect the user back to where they came from after they login?

I'm sending to the user to the login page with this link: `/spring_security_login?redirect=/item5`. After loging in, I expect the user to be redirected to `/item5` page. However, they're always redirected to `/` page.

Here is the configuration I'm using:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
</http>
<beans:bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
    <beans:property name="targetUrlParameter" value="redirect"/>
</beans:bean>
```

It seems that `targetUrlParameter` is not getting picked up as expected. I'm using Spring Security 3.1.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following rules are applied when using the [`SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.html):

> - If the alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl property is set to true, the defaultTargetUrl property will be used for the destination.
> - If a parameter matching the value of targetUrlParameter has been set on the request, the value will be used as the destination. By default this has the value "spring-security-redirect".
> - If the useReferer property is set, the "Referer" HTTP header value will be used, if present.
> - As a fallback option, the defaultTargetUrl value will be used.

According to your configuration, this should work. My guess is that you didn't propagate the `referer` when sending the `POST` request in the form login. Typically, you should write the `referer` value in an hidden field in your login page, so that the `referer` parameter is transmitted to `spring_security_login`.

Comment: I'm trying to get it working with the default login page that Spring Security provides, so I'm not manually setting or propagating anything on the login page. I'm not following how to set the `referer`, since it seems like it can't simply be set like `/spring_security_login?referer=somePage`

Comment: I don't see an other way than rendering the login page yourself (and take care of the `referer` paramater. Most of time, you will need this, since the default login page from Spring is ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Change **SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler** to **SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler** and be happy.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

it because of this line :

```
<beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
```

remove that line and try again.

Comment: I removed that line and it did not change the behavior. The login page always redirects to `/` even without that line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Even if the url of the page is typed on the browser in which case `referer` is not captured, `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` uses the previous url captured by the `ExceptionTraslationFilter`.

Read http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#form-login-flow-handling and http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html

Comment: Good information on the referer.  I would not depend on it.  Spring will capture the original request info in the requestCache.  Anyone encountering similar issues as the OP should use debugger and step through the SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler Spring code.  It is easy to follow how they redirect to the user's original intended page.

Answer (score 0):

The following generic solution can be used with regular login, a Spring Social login, or most other Spring Security filters.

In your Spring MVC controller, when loading the read-only page, save the path to the page in the session if user has not been logged in. In XML config, set the default target url. For example:

In your Spring MVC controller, the redirect method should read out the path from the session and return `redirect:<my_saved_page_path>`.

So, after user logs in, they'll be sent to `/redirect` page, which will promptly redirect them back to the page that they last visited.

Answer (score 0):

LaurentG has already explained this. You can pass the useReferer param in spring. Works fine for both SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Here is your modified spring logic:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
     <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
     <beans:property name="targetUrlParameter" value="redirect"/>
     <beans:property name="useReferer" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: there is a typo, it should be SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler