# Link to log in with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've got a web application that uses spring security and spring mvc.  Some of the pages are protected using security:intercept-urls, and others are not protected at all.  Of the pages that are not protected, one of them has content for anonymous users and content for authenticated users, which is being differentiated using the spring security tag "authorize".  On these pages I want to give users the option to log in to view all of the content.  It seems that if I directly link to my custom login page it doesn't redirect the user to the content page after successful log in.  Is there any way to link to the login page so it returns to the referring URL (or a user specified URL) upon successful authentication?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked here [Spring Security targetUrlParameter does not redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779366/spring-security-targeturlparameter-does-not-redirect).

You can use the parameter `spring-security-redirect` to pass through the destination URL (your content page) where you want to land after successful login. This parameter would need to be passed to the login form from the content page, and then the login form would need to place it in a hidden field so that it gets propagated to Spring Security with the rest of the login request.

More info [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/57051-redirect-spring-security)