# How to change Login Success Url in Spring mvc Login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to send url from our form submit for where control after successfully login.This is mu bean which i have create after successfully login.

Can you help me how i will send value of targetUrlParameter from submitting form in spring Security.

```
<beans:bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/default.htm"/>
    <beans:property name="targetUrlParameter" value="spring-security-redirect"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: @Charajeet will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779366/spring-security-targeturlparameter-does-not-redirect) help

Answer (score 0):

you mean someting like this?

```
<sec:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <!-- sec:intercept-url pattern="/secured/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https"/-->
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="..." />

        <sec:form-login login-page="/login/login.htm"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="..." />

</sec:http>
```